# if type(X) == type(Y) boolean triggering as false when it's the same type

Tags: python

I have a small bit of code in a class (`Delta_Viewer`) that looks like this:

```
class Delta_Viewer():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df : pd.Dataframe = df       
        self._columns = trade_types
    # init method, properties, etc up here
        
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if type(other) == Delta_Viewer:        
            new_df = self.df.sub(other.df, fill_value = 0)
            return Delta_Viewer(new_df)
        else:
            print(type(other), 'self:', type(self))            
            print(id(other), 'self:', id(self))            
            raise Exception(f'Delta Viewer can only be subtracted from another Delta_Viewer instance. passed: {type(other)}')    
            
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__sub__(other)
```

What's confusing me is that when a separate part of my code tries to subtract one `Delta_Viewer` instance from another, my Exception gets raised.  To try and debug, I added in the `print()` statements, which show that they are the same type.

```
<class 'Sitka.Portfolio.delta_gamma.Delta_Viewer'> self: <class 'Sitka.Portfolio.delta_gamma.Delta_Viewer'>
1681758064352 self: 1681751071136
```

I also tried the same if-statement with `isinstance()`, but that didn't work either.

PS. There are no class decorators. Its a fairly simple class that has 4 properties that return predefined functions on self.df.

Comment: The most likely culprits seem to be either module reloading (which would create a new `Delta_Viewer` class), or assigning something to `Delta_Viewer` (potentially because of a class decorator you didn't show us), but we can't tell for sure what's going on from just this.

Comment: Oh -whats module reloading?  That sounds promising, as whats weirder (to me) is if I run the same code twice, the exception wont get thrown

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: Unrelated: that `__rsub__` makes no sense. You're implementing `x - some_delta_viewer` as `some_delta_viewer - x` for any `x` that doesn't have its own implementation of the operation. First, the argument order is wrong, and second, `Delta_Viewer` doesn't actually know how to handle `some_delta_viewer - x` for any `x` that isn't already a `DeltaViewer`.

Comment: Don't compare types directly. Use `isinstance(other, Delta_Viewer)`.

Comment: @chepner isinstance didn't work either (I tried that / mentioned that in the question).

Comment: @user2357112 could you provide some more information on how to address module reloading?  I hear you on the __rsub__ too, I didn't really put much thought into that clearly.  I blame my kids keeping me up at night

Comment: Is `Delta_Viewer` defined at the file-level scope, or is it inside another block such as a function definition? Classes defined inside other blocks may have surprising behavior.

Comment: @keynesiancross: Well, if you don't know what module reloading is, you're *probably* not using it. It'd happen with [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) or stuff like [IPython `autoreload`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html). It basically reexecutes a module's code to try to reflect changes you made since you first imported it, but it's a massive source of weird errors and not really a good idea most of the time.

Comment: Oh - I am using IPython / Spyder.  Which makes me think that could be the issue.  I do use %autoreload 2, mostly because it makes me debugging 100x easier.

Comment: So you *are* reloading modules. As I said, it's a massive source of weird errors, and this is one of those weird errors it causes.

Comment: got you...  doh.  Any way around it / any way I can rewrite the code to accommodate that?

Comment: There aren't really any clean options for getting this kind of stuff to work with module reloading. Mostly, you just end up making bigger messes if you try.